# jQuery: How to find an image by its src

Tags: jquery

I need to find an img by name and src. I have been trying the following to no avail.

```
var s = $("img[src='/images/greendot.gif'][name='BS']");
```

The html:

```
<img alt="This item is active." name="BS" src="/images/greendot.gif"/>
```

vs

```
<img alt="This item is not active." name="BS" src="/images/spacer.gif"/>
```

Comment: By name and source, are you trying to find multiple images?

Comment: can you post an example of the html?

Comment: yes I am. The s var will be an array whose length I will check.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

without seeing the html I would say check your path.

```
$("img[src$='greendot.gif'][name='BS']")
```

given the following HTML:

```
<img src="http://assets0.twitter.com/images/twitter_logo_header.png" name="logo" />
```

this jquery worked:

```
var x = $("img[src$='twitter_logo_header.png'][name='logo']");
alert(x.attr("src"));
```

Comment: There's no need for a $ when we have the full path.

Answer (score 6):

Try losing the quotes:

```
var s = $("img[src=../../images/greendot.gif][name=BS]");
```

Comment: Try with the path you've shown in the HTML, i.e. ../../images/greendot.gif. I've edited the answer.

Comment: There was a mixup there. I originally had ../../images/greendot.gif and it still wasnt working. I then switched to /images on the dynamically add images (js added) but the ones coming down from .net where still ../. At any rate something about the '/' in the attr search were screwing things up.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers add full path to src, href and similar attributes. So even though element is defined with relative path, in DOM 'src' attribute contains domain name and full path. Using [src$="..."] syntax or specifying full domain name seem to be only options for finding images by src with jQuery.

---

I might be wrong here. src property of image object reports full path, but the attribute should contain path as specified in the code. [src="relative/path"] works in the latest jQuery version, maybe it was an early version where it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Change your img tag like this:

```
<img src="path/to/imgage/img.jpg" title="img.jpg" />
```

I mean add to your images title attribute and set them name of file.

When you need to access sertain image you can do it as below:

```
//Finding image that you need using 'title' attribute; 
var imageTag = $("img[title='imageName']");

//Then if you need to do something with it;
imageTag.attr('src', 'path/to/newImage/newImage.jgp');
imageTag.attr('title', 'newImage.jpg');
```

Comment: Why the down vote people, it's not an elegant way to skin this cat but hey! that is one skinless cat people.