# How to find number of specific images on page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an .aspx view that dynamically adds validation images to the page at runtime using some built in validation we added into the models. When you look at the code for the view, you can't see all of the image tags (which are instead generated on the fly). However, I would like a way to know whether or not any of these specific image tags are contained in the HTML that the user sees. Basically I want to know if the page has passed validation or not.

The image tag is this (found using the pointer tool of firebug, similar to Developer Tools in IE):

```
<img src="/Extranet/img/exclamation.gif" class="validation">
```

What would be a way of finding out if any of these images are on the current HTML page that the user sees (remember this can change when certain fields are updated), in JQuery, to know when the user has gotten rid of them all and therefore passed validation.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835378/jquery-how-to-find-an-image-by-its-src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if( $('.validation').length > 0 )
{
   //images exist
}
```

This will check if there are any items with class `validation` on the page. To limit to just image checking, use `img.validation`.

Comment: I added for clarity. Not every language assumes 0 == false, and if (numeric) can be confusing for non-JS developers. If your team is and always will be strong JS devs, drop the > 0 if you wish. I'd say this should probably be a compilation fix, rather than a source-code one. I'm not sure if google's clojure compiler does this, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: @Sime no it's not but it's useful to explain to someone who doesn't understan what it's doing - You thought that was sufficient for a downvote? +1 from me as I think that was unreasonable - especially as this answer works and was the first one...

Comment: @Basiclife I didn't downvote. It seems that the answerers have a downvote battle here :)

Comment: @Sime apologies for the assumption - and it seems you're right lol

Comment: @Basiclife Actually, I think that one person down-voted all three answers for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('img.validation').length ) {
    //images exist
}
```