# Jquery add class attribute src img

Tags: jquery

I tried to add a class to the following HTML code with jquery:

```
<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 37px; height: 94px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png">
```

I tried doing this with this code and a few other ways but it did not work

```
<script>
  $( 'img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png"]' ).addClass("selected");
</script>
```

**where is my error?**

Comment: Why not use an ID or class? I understand that that's not answering the question, but it may be easier.

Comment: You also haven't closed the img tag.

Comment: @Liam Spencer: You only need to close the image tag in XHTML, it's perfectly valid HTML.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835378/jquery-how-to-find-an-image-by-its-src

Comment: Because i need to add a class to a gmap output

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way is to add an identifier to your image tag. This can be a class or ID:

```
<img id="mapfile-image" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png">
```

This way you can add your class by targeting the identifier:

```
$('#mapfile-image').addClass("selected");
```

Comment: This is a google map, i need a class for customize it taht is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("img[src='http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png']").addClass("selected")
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are missed to add ready function :

Try this :

```
        <script>
            $(function(){ // ready function
                $('img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png"]').addClass("selected");
            });
        </script>
```

Your code :

```
<script>
  $( 'img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png"]' ).addClass("selected");
</script>
```

your code get executed before your image element loaded. Hence try putting you jquery code inside ready function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify anywhere when you want this action to take place. Obviously you must wait for the document to load so the img will exist on the page before you add a class to it. this can be done by changing your script to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('img[src$="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png"]').addClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

Notice that we are waiting for the document to be ready before we add the class to it.

Comment: also not works, i try to put in header and in bottom but there are no change.

Comment: Edited my answer, added a-$ after the word `src` in the select

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img[src*="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/smc.png"]').addClass('selected');
});
```

Hope that helps :)