# Function to change the image onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how is it possible to look for an specific image on a page and replace it with some other image on page load.

for example, I have this on my site :

```
<img src="/content/public/1472.png">
```

I want to find this image and change it with the below value on page load :

```
<img src="/content/public/1473.png">
```

Comment: Maybe by providing an `id` to that element and updating it on `document load` event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to find an image by its src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835378/jquery-how-to-find-an-image-by-its-src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr()` or `prop()` in ready function :

```
$(function(){
    $('img[src="/content/public/1472.png"]').attr('src', '/content/public/1473.png');
    //$('img[src="/content/public/1472.png"]').prop('src', '/content/public/1473.png');
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  console.log('Before : '+$("img").attr('src'));

  $('img[src="http://www.drodd.com/images15/1-4.png"]').attr('src', 'http://www.drodd.com/images15/2-4.png');

  console.log('After : '+$("img").attr('src'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.drodd.com/images15/1-4.png">
```

Comment: Since jQuery 1.6, you can use `prop()` method instead of `attr()` method.

Comment: @zakaria-acharki thanks a lot. It seems good. To load it on page load should i just add $(document).ready(function () ?

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps... `$(function(){ })` is a shorthand for $( document ).ready(function(){ }). (if you have already the ready function just add the code inside it)

Comment: @zakaria-acharki just a small problem. It actually loads my first image on page load and only after 5 sec it changes to the new image. Is there a way to make it appear right away?

Comment: That because JS wait for DOM to fully load then execute the code inside ready function...

Comment: @zakaria-acharki Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Using JS no since it should wait for element to load then could use it.

Comment: @zakaria-acharki do you have any suggestion to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  alert("By default image path is:"+$('img').attr("src"));
  if($('img').attr("src")=="/content/public/1472.png")  //to find the image
    {
  $('img').attr("src","/content/public/1473.png"); 
  alert("changed image src is:"+$('img').attr("src"));
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/content/public/1472.png">
```

Is this what you want.